# Visualizing a frozen graph_def.pb

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorboard

I am wondering how to go about visualization of my frozen graph def. I need it to figure out my tensorflow networks input and output nodes. I have already tried several methods to no avail, like the summarize graph tool. Does anyone have an answer for some things that I can try? I am open to clarifying questions, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use TensorBoard. It is on the Tensorflow website...